# Checking if email already exists in Mongo Atlas DB w/ async and await

Tags: node.js

Trying to check if email provided by the user during the registration step already exists in my Mongo Atlas DB. This is the code I have. I get response.status(409) for all emails regardless of whether email exists in DB or it doesn't. Thank you and appreciate any input.

```
  const userExists = await checkIfUserExists(email);
  if (userExists) return res.status(409).json(message.fail('User with this email already exists.'));

async function checkIfUserExists(email) {
  return User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then( () => true)
      .catch(() => false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function checkIfUserExists(email) {
  return User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then(user => user ? true : false)
      .catch(() => false);
}
```

I don't think that mongoose will throw an Error if it can't find a user. It'll just return null or undefined in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning true even if the user is not found

```
const userExists = await checkIfUserExists(email);
if (userExists) return res.status(409).json(message.fail('User with this email already exists.'));

async function checkIfUserExists(email) {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  return !!user;
}
```